# How to not able to hit the controller in my asp.net mvc application using this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    GOTO = function () {
        alert("yes");
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index/",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Ohh Yaa Success");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="JavaScript:GOTO()" />

</asp:Content>
```

My Controller ActionResult is something like this
JsonResult

```
  [HttpPost]
        public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Index(FormCollection collection)
        {
            //return Content("<xml>this is just test</xml>", "text/xml");
            //return Content("this is just test", "text/plain");

            if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                return Json(new { id = 1, value = "new" });
            }
            else if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/xml") ||
                     Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("text/xml"))
            {

            }
            if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("text/html"))
            {
                //return View();
            }

           return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
        }
```

I am not able to return the JsonResult here allways I am getting popupmessage saying u have choosen to open this dialogue? is there something I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Can you include where your datastring variable is being set as well as the method signature for your controller? That seems like the most likely culprit

Comment: You are getting the popup dialog because the data coming back is unable to be interpreted by the model binder, and so the browser is treating it like a downloadable file or some kind of debugger interrupted code. Basically you're not returning what the controller is expecting. It expects a form collection, you're returning Json data.

Comment: what do I need to change the code Ciel? thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual class type that you are serializing to json? The Json model binding by default expects specific types, you're expecting Json to be interpreted from a generic formcollection. Please post the class that is being used in your View and I can help you more from there.

Comment: I've added a new post showing it a bit more. Basically you are passing `Json` to your Controller, but it is expecting `FormCollection`. Json is just a string, so change your controller to expect a string, and then you can deserialize it in the controller.

Comment: Also, I tidied up the javascript a bit - unless your script is executing inside of an inherited block of script code (which from the looks of things, it isn't), it is healthy to always make sure your jquery runs when the document is finished loading, hence the `$(document)ready(function() { });` syntax I included. There is a cleaner way of doing this but it escapes me off the top of my head. Also, I modified the code to just fire when the form is submitted, so you do not need to wire your submit button up.

Comment: And then there is the change from `$.ajax` to `$.post`. `$.ajax` expects a response back - which may be what you want, but `$.post` posts to the controller directly. I think either way will work, but I try to use `$.post` unless I explicitly need to use `$.ajax` - that may be personal preference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead -- and make sure jQuery is loaded first.  Note the changes to apply the handler via jQuery instead of inline, serializing the data, generating the URL in code dynamically rather than hard-coded, and returning false from the click handler to prevent normal form submission.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
          var data = $('form').serialize();  // or however you get your data
          $.ajax({
              cache: false,
              type: "POST",
              url: "<%= Html.Action( "index", "home" ) %>",
              data: data,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  alert("Ohh Yaa Success");
              }
          });
          return false; // don't do the normal submit
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" value="submit" />
```

Comment: thanks tvanfosson,but I am not geting the JsonResult back thanks

Comment: @kumar From your additional description, it looks like the pop-up is coming because you're doing a normal form submit.  Did you add the return false in the handler to prevent that?

Comment: yes I did that. but I am getting same problem again..its opening popup window.

Comment: @kumar - you've got a javascript error somewhere, I'm betting.  Use Firefox/Firebug and check the console for messages.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the button in a form tag and call the GOTO function in onsubmit event

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `data: datastring` might be the problem. Check to make sure that the name of your data parameter is the same as your method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to approach it more like this ...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(form).submit(function() {
        alert("yes");
        $.post({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index/",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Ohh Yaa Success");
            }
        });
      });
    }
</script>

<form>
   // your form fields
   <input type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

And then your controller should look more like this.

> Notice how we changed the parameter to a string that matches your jQuery `data` field.

```
[HttpPost]
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Index(string datastring)
{
    // you can deserialize your Json here.

    //return Content("<xml>this is just test</xml>", "text/xml");
    //return Content("this is just test", "text/plain");

    if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
    {
        return Json(new { id = 1, value = "new" });
    }
    else if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/xml") ||
             Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("text/xml"))
    {

    }
    if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("text/html"))
    {
        //return View();
    }

   return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
}
```